# HTTP error issue in suggest query using Solarium php

Tags: php, solr, solarium

I'm implement suggest query in php codeigiter using solarium. But while connect to the `createSuggester` query. It shows following error line.

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Solarium\Exception\HttpException

Message: Solr HTTP error: OK (404)
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /solr/../suggest. Reason:

    Not Found
Filename: C:\wamp\www\solariumphp\vendor\solarium\solarium\src\Core\Query\Result\Result.php

Line Number: 59

Backtrace:

File: C:\wamp\www\solariumphp\vendor\solarium\solarium\src\Core\Client\Client.php
Line: 751
Function: __construct

File: C:\wamp\www\solariumphp\vendor\solarium\solarium\src\Core\Client\Client.php
Line: 783
Function: createResult

File: C:\wamp\www\solariumphp\vendor\solarium\solarium\src\Core\Client\Client.php
Line: 978
Function: execute

File: C:\wamp\www\solariumphp\application\controllers\Example.php
Line: 30
Function: suggester

File: C:\wamp\www\solariumphp\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

My sample code is here,

```
$query = $this->client->createSuggester();
$query->setQuery('ap ip v'); //multiple terms
$query->setDictionary('suggester');
// $query->setOnlyMorePopular(true);
$query->setCount(10);
// $query->setCollate(true);

// this executes the query and returns the result
$resultset = $this->client->suggester($query);

echo '<b>Query:</b> '.$query->getQuery().'<hr/>';

// display results for each term
foreach ($resultset as $term => $termResult) {
    echo '<h3>' . $term . '</h3>';
    echo 'NumFound: '.$termResult->getNumFound().'<br/>';
    echo 'StartOffset: '.$termResult->getStartOffset().'<br/>';
    echo 'EndOffset: '.$termResult->getEndOffset().'<br/>';
    echo 'Suggestions:<br/>';
    foreach ($termResult as $result) {
        echo '- '.$result.'<br/>';
    }

    echo '<hr/>';
}

// display collation
echo 'Collation: '.$resultset->getCollation();
```

I'm try to find solution in many resources. But the solution is not there. Plese explain me what/why this issue is happened?

Comment: Is `/solr/../` actually the URL shown, or have you removed something here? As it seems to be missing a core / collection name, that's what's giving you the 404 first of all

Comment: Url is `solr/test_core/suggest.`.

Comment: In that case, have you added the `/suggest` requestHandler as [shown in the reference guide](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/suggester.html)? There's ready-to-copy configuration available as part of the example cores (techproducts iirc) bundled with Solr.

Comment: I try this solution. But solarium suggester returning no result.

Comment: Any one who help me how to get value from solarium

Comment: You'll have to provide more details - if you've tried something and it didn't do what you expected - what was the result? Does the URL work directly in your browser? Does it work in the Solr interface?

Comment: My output is like there

Comment: {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":3},
  "suggest":{"mySuggester":{
      "USS":{
        "numFound":0,
        "suggestions":[]}}}}

Comment: I run via brower

Comment: But that's a different error than what Solarium is telling you - you'll need to find out what the difference in URLs are - Solarium is saying it's getting a 404 not found, so it's apparently requesting a different URL than what the admin interface is using in the background. Use "developer tools" and the "network" pane in your browser to see where the request ends up (and the query interface in the admin page should show the URL as well) and compare it to what Solarium is complaining about.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the default dictionary in "solrconfig.xml" like this:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
<lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">FreeTextLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">content</str>
    <str name="suggestFreeTextAnalyzerFieldType">suggestTypeLc</str>
    <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
    <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
</lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
<lst name="defaults">
    <str name="suggest">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    <str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str>
</lst>
<arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>
```

and remove this line from your code :

```
$query->setDictionary('suggester');
```

Answer (score 0):

not `'suggester'`  at `$query->setDictionary('suggester')`,please  use the name of the suggester like `$query->setDictionary('mySuggester')`